# What data structure to use to store 1000 customers sorted by age

Tags: c#, data-structures, hashtable

I want to save around 1000 or so customer records in-memory where the records would be sorted by age. I would be looking up customer's using age as my search criteria or may have to walk through the list to fetch all the customer in order of ascending age.

One idea I have is to create an array implementation of a Hash Table with size 110 (as ago could vary from 0 to 110 years for example). Each Hash Table slot would correspond to age/years, I could then use separate chaining to keep a linked list of all the customers of that age.

Though above methodology would solve my purpose, I am not sure if this is the optimum way of doing what I need.

Technology involved would with C# and  Windows Forms.

Comment: You can use below suggestions. As per my past experience, sorting 800 records were  taking about 1.5 seconds. records started to increase. We shifted the logic to database.

Comment: *1000 records* is nothing. Use any data structure you like.

Comment: you can find optimum solution of this probelm after calculate time comlexity and space complexity of this probelm.

Comment: @PKKG 1.5 seconds for 800 records!! What technology or sorting algorithm do you use?

Comment: This is a "shopping" question and therefore offtopic for SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer to use `Generic List<T>` for the purpose. And can be manipulated with `LINQ` as you wish.

Comment: Thanks, I think I can use it. Giving it a shot now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hashset`. It is a type of collection in C# and is pretty fast.

Comment: `HashSet` would not allow multiple User with the same age if the hashing function is based on the `Age` property.

Answer (score 0):

create a class with the necessary properties like first_name and last_name etc. Then create a Dictionary where the key of the dictionary is unique and the value of the dictionary is an instance of that class.

```
 public class User
 {
     public string firstName{get;set;}
     public string lastName{get;set;}
 }
```

your dictionary:

```
 Dictionary<int, User> UserList = new Dictionary<int, User>();
```

With dictionary you can use linq to get query from it or find a specific user by id.

Comment: Can't use a `Dictionary` here, he needs more than one `User` in an age key.

Comment: @SimonBelanger it doesn't matter. he can grab all users with a certain age using foreach.

Comment: Of course it matters. If you key is the age, and you have Marie Doe, age 34, and Jane Doe, age 34, you won't be able to have them both in your dictionary, much less iterate the dictionary to find them both.

Comment: @SimonBelanger dear simon, you didn't get what I meant, by using foreach you can iterate through all object in your dictionary and then check the age of each object.
I didn't say that the age is key. the key has to be unique like user name

Comment: @SimonBelanger I think it doesn't matter anymore. we are discussing over a useless matter. :) 
he probably either got his answer or forgot about it.

Comment: Thanks SimonBelanger and Daniel. What SimonBelanger mentioned is exactly what I would run into if I use Dictionary. Anyways, Due to urgency of the issue and relatively less data we are going with Generic List<T> implementation for now. Thanks for you help and time.

Answer (score 0):

If there are only 2 values that you need to store then you can use Dictionary, else you can create entity and use List of it.

Comment: Dictionary wont let me add same key (age) twice. Anyways, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

SortedList might be better than HashSet depending on how you are using the data.

Comment: Thanks, Haven't tried SortedList but giving List<T> and Linq a short before that.